# Water Damage to desktop tower but not turned on

Tags: desktop, water-damage

I just spilled a lot of water onto my desktop which seeped through the fan vents on top of the computer. everything got drenched in water graphics card, ram, motherboard, psu hdd, ssd. i have not tried to turn it on yet but i fear for the death of my computer if i do try... Should the computer be ok because it was not plugged into an outlet? (it was turned off and then unplugged from an outlet for about 30 minutes before the water spilled)

P.s. 
my cpu is liquid cooled with the corsair hydro series.. should the cpu be fine or could the water come into contact with the cpu via the radiator and tubes that connect to the cpu?

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Anything that got wet should be washed with distilled  water,  then dried.  There are special ovens for drying circuit boards, about 150F, enough to vaporize water but not too hot for plastic and electrolytic caps.  Ordinary baking ovens are too hot.  Instead try a wet/dry vac, followed with drying in the sun.

Comment: If your living area is air conditioned, leave the side cover off for 4 days, it will dry on its own.

Comment: You can also use rice to absorb the humidity.  It does so very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the side panel, turn it face down for a day so the water drips off. Then for another 2 days, turn it back up normally with a fan on it. Or without a fan for 4 days.

It also depends on the water in your area and how much contaminants it has in it.

Fingers crossed!